# btrfs receive to <mount-point>/?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

Suppose I have a BTRFS filesystem A with a read-only subvolume at `<mount-point-A>/snaps/good-one`. I want to create a BTRFS filesystem B (could be on the same or another machine) which will contain the *contents* of that subvolume at `<mount-point-B>/` — in normal read-write mode.

Is there any way to employ `btrfs send/receive` to achieve that? Like maybe receive the subvolume read-only at `<mount-point-B>/good-one` and then somehow switch it to be read-write at `<mount-point-B>/`? Or do I have to fallback to `rsync`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### TL;DR

```
btrfs sub set-default <VolumeID> ./
```

##### Full answer

Assuming we have received a read-only volume at `<mount-point-B>/good-one`:

Make it read-write:

```
cd mount-point-B
sudo btrfs property set -ts ./good-one ro false
```

Obtain its ID:

```
sudo btrfs sub show ./good-one | grep "Subvolume ID"
```

Make it sit at the root:

```
sudo btrfs sub set-default <Subvolume ID> ./
```

Re-mount is required to see the root volume change. The original root volume becomes hidden.

Here is a full test script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sudo modprobe loop
cd /tmp
fallocate -l 128M btrfs1 && \
fallocate -l 128M btrfs2 && \
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 ./btrfs1 && \
sudo losetup /dev/loop1 ./btrfs2 && \
sudo mkfs.btrfs -q /dev/loop0 && \
sudo mkfs.btrfs -q /dev/loop1 && \
mkdir btrfs1m && \
mkdir btrfs2m && \
sudo mount /dev/loop0 btrfs1m && \
sudo mount /dev/loop1 btrfs2m && \
sudo touch btrfs1m/file1 && \
sudo touch btrfs2m/file2 && \
sudo btrfs sub snapshot -r btrfs1m/ btrfs1m/s1 && \
sudo btrfs send btrfs1m/s1 | sudo btrfs receive btrfs2m/ && \
sudo umount /dev/loop0 && \
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0 && \
rm btrfs1 && \
rmdir btrfs1m && \
cd btrfs2m
VID=$(sudo btrfs sub show ./s1 | grep "Subvolume ID" | tr -dc '0-9')
sudo btrfs property set -ts ./s1 ro false && \
sudo btrfs sub set-default $VID ./ && \
cd .. && \
sudo umount /dev/loop1 && \
sudo mount /dev/loop1 btrfs2m && \
echo "Now the received volume sits at the root:" && \
ls btrfs2m && \
sudo mv btrfs2m/file1 btrfs2m/renamed && \
sudo umount /dev/loop1 && \
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop1 && \
rm btrfs2 && \
rmdir btrfs2m
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've received the read-only subvolume, create a `rw` snapshot of it and optionally delete the read-only one.

Comment: How to make it sit at `<mount-point-B>/`?

Comment: You can't receive in a subfolder of the end subvolume so you'll need to receive it in `<mount-point-B>-recv` (for example) and make the rw snapshot at `<mount-point-B>`.

Answer (score 0):

While `btrfs receive` will automatically set the subvolume to read-only, you can always change it afterwards. This, however, will remove any protections from the copy being an exact duplicate of the original.

After the receive is complete, run this on `<mount-point-B>`:

```
sudo btrfs property set <mount-point-B> ro false
```

Now, if you don't want to mess with the integrity of the backup, then create a `rw` snapshot as @Ginnungagap suggested.

Comment: The question is not how to make a RO volume RW, but how to position it at the root of the mount point i.e. `<mount-point-B>/` as opposed to `<mount-point-B>/<volumeName>`.